# How to switch back and forth between command mode and other modes in VIM without losing the typed command?

Tags: vim, neovim

Recently I started using [Neovim](https://neovim.io/) on my Ubuntu default terminal (gnome-terminal), and I had to look for the most used shortcuts so that I could become more productive in a short period of time.

My problem now is I don't know how to switch back and forth between command mode and other modes on vim without losing the typed words in the command mode.

[image: Neovim on gnome-terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. It's pretty simple but, there might be a better answer for this.

I had to go back to command mode with `shift` + `:` then pressing `up` arrow to show the last typed command.

Comment: There is also `q:` which will bring up the command line window. See `:h cmdwin` & `:h q:`. Related Vimcasts episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

Comment: Thank you, I found a better way by mapping `<leader>` + `t` to switch to command mode and press up key `:nnoremap <leader>t :<up>`, this saves my left hand from having to go all the way to the up key and back